# Insert form does not works as the edit query is coded in single form

Tags: php, database, forms, mysqli, pdo

I was converting my existing PHP MySQLi code to PDO. In it, I made a single form that will add and update the data. My edit is working without any issue but whenever I select to add form an error appears for invalid argument supplied for foreach loop. And due to this add is not working. Here I made functions for add, update and fetch the data by id. The function for add is:

```
    function addSchool($schoolName) {
    global $connect;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO school (schoolName) VALUES (:schoolName)";
    $query = $connect -> prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':schoolName',$schoolName,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query -> execute();
    if($query){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function for edit is:

```
function editSchool($schoolId, $schoolName)
{
    global $connect;
    $sql = "update school set schoolName = :schoolName where schoolId = :schoolId ";
    $query = $connect->prepare($sql);
    $query -> bindParam(':schoolId', $schoolId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query -> bindParam(':schoolName' , $schoolName , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query -> execute();
    if($query){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the function used to get data by id for edit purpose is:

```
    function getSchoolById($schoolId)
{
    global $connect;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM school where schoolId = :schoolId";
    // preparing the query
    $query = $connect->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':schoolId',$schoolId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $result;
  
}
```

The way I utilized above functions in HTML/PHP file is :

```
<?php
include_once("includes/connect.php");
include_once("function.php");

$editState = false;
$schoolById = "";
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $schoolName = $_POST['schoolName'];
    $saveSchool = addSchool($schoolName);
    $lastInsertId = $connect->lastInsertId();
    if ($lastInsertId) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show'>
        <strong>Success!</strong> School Added.
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
    </div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show'>
        <strong>Error!</strong> School not added.
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
    </div>";
    }
    
    }
    if (isset($_GET['schoolId'])) {
        $schoolId = $_GET['schoolId'];
        $editState = true;
        $schoolById = getSchoolById($schoolId);
    } 


if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {
 
    $schoolName = $_POST['schoolName'];
    $updateSchool = editSchool($schoolId, $schoolName);
    if ($updateSchool) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show'>
        <strong>Success!</strong> School Updated.
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
    </div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show'>
        <strong>Error!</strong> School not updated.
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
    </div>";
    }
} 

?>
```

And below is my form for add and update. It is the single form through which upon selecting add the add opens and upon selection of edit, edit form appears:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <?php 
            foreach ($schoolById as $school) {  
            ?>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>School Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" name="schoolName" value="<?php echo $school->schoolName;  ?>">
                </div>
       
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php if ($editState == true) : ?>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="edit">Update School</button>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="add">Add School</button>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div> 
        <?php      
         }
        ?>
```

I am not getting the point of how to remove this invalid foreach argument. Moreover, when `$schoolById` is declared then errors are removed from add school form but form disappears and the edit school form works smoothly. Now I want to know that how to get this issue resolved.

Comment: _“I am not getting the point of how to remove this invalid foreach argument.”_ - either provide a data structure in `$schoolById`, that foreach can actually loop over - or _don’t_ try to loop over anything, if you don’t _have_ any actual data to loop over at this point.

Comment: *"when `$schoolById` is declared then errors are removed"* Then you should define `$schoolById`. Why can't you do this?

Comment: FYI: This `if($query){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }` is wrong. $query is not a boolean expression

Comment: So what shall I write in if($query) to make syntax right

Comment: Have you tried ```if ($query->execute){ return true; }else { return false; }```?

Comment: I solved the issue. There was an issue in the separation of values passed by query.